# XPATH of element with the same class name

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

How can I create an Xpath for individual elements within the same class name? The element ids (eg. id='some_item_12') is not constant (ie. could be 12,3, etc on next iteration) so I can't use a direct xpath to the element.

I have used the one below but it fetches the first element in that class eg.  //*[@id='someitem_12']/td[5]/div/a[1] while I want a[2]

//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]

Thanks.

LP

Comment: There are lots of ways it could be done - but without seeing more of the html to understand the structure, it's difficult to recommend any one way of doing it.

Comment: I'll explain the scenario: I have a set of rules that I can add to a Rule_list and each rule created has an edit and delete button. Assume that's what needs automation ie. creating a rule, editing it and deleting it after verifying the working functionality. The issue here is that each time I want to delete the rule, the button's name "rule_input_id" keeps changing ie. it's rule_input_12 or 2 etc so the test fails. How would you suggest going about that? 

<a href="6" class="tabs_link edit_rule btn btn-primary margin-small-right"> 
<input type="hidden" class="rule_inp_id" value="6">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've got it but I'm sure there are better ways of doing it.

//*[contains(@id,'someitem_')]/a[2]  //worked for me

Answer (score 1):

**Looks ok**

You can also use findElements which will return a list of all elements.
From there you can iterate on the result list and find the element you were looking for